# Where can I purchase a TSA lock & what is the cost?

Tags: usa, luggage, tsa

Where can I buy a TSA lock & how expensive are they?

Comment: Amazon, different prices. They’re cheap

Answer (score 1):

You can buy them at pretty much every travel store and on [Amazon.](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?k=tsa%20lock) They’re cheap.